# Asus FA617NS-N3085W keyboard is not recognized and several other issues (ACPI BIOS Error (bug))

Tags: 22.04, bios, acpi

I face several issues with my new notebook (model as above). While I understand that graphics might not yet be supported, I have the problem, that my internal keyboard isn't working. I use Ubuntu 22.04. The processor is Ryzen7 7735hs graphics Radeon RX 7600s.

`dmesg` output gives me the following errors:

```
[    0.267052] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_TZ.TZ01], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
[    0.267057] fbcon: Taking over console
[    0.267067] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
[    0.267070] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: ThermalZone (0x5B85)
[    0.269260] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/dswload2-162)   
[    0.269264] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
[    0.269266] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)
[    0.269267] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP2.WWAN], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/dswload2-162)
[    0.269270] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
[    0.269272] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)
[    0.269508] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.GPP6.WLAN._S0W], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
[    0.269511] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
[    0.945006] hub 6-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.945009] hub 6-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)
[    4.110988] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Failed to add dm ip block(DCE_HWIP:0x30201)
[    4.111008] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Fatal error during GPU init
[    4.111015] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: amdgpu: finishing device.
```

If any additional information is needed, I'm happy to give a follow-up.

Comment: Just wanted to add, that i have the latest bios installed and checking for updates. made also a request at asus, to get additional help here. normally they advertised this one is compatible to ubuntu.

Comment: Tried also 22.10, but it's the same issue.

Comment: Tired Ubuntu 23.04 with Kernel 6.2 while I've read somewhere else, that it ight be gone with newer kernel, but it's the same. dmesg same output as on 22.04

Comment: Please, I really would need some help here please. What inputs do you need here?

Comment: Just received an bios update, Version 306 now. all issues persist.